# Disk space lost after shrinking partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have my SSD partitioned into two 128 GB disks. I was managing my disk space and decided to shrink one of my partitions (the one with Mavericks) because it had more free disk space, in order to transfer this space into my main drive (the one with El Capitan).

As I couldn't just transfer space from Mavericks to El Capitan I shrank my Mavericks partition, but then my total disk space was reduced. I did everything I could without success.

Macbook Pro Retina Late 2013 13" (256 GB SSD)

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Reboot Into [recoverymode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)
2. Select disk utility
3. First try to use first aid on your drive
4. And then use first aid on each partition.

Comment: Already tried it, but it says that everything's ok.

Comment: Can't edit last comment.

I also tried this solution without success.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148473/reclaim-delete-freespace-partition-after-yosemite-removal

Thanks btw!

Comment: Try to create a new partition by splitting up one, did you do step 3? Do you have a Time Machine backup?

Comment: I don't think that it'll work, and I may end up losing more disk space. I do have a Time Machine backup, maybe I should do a clean Sierra install.

Comment: I read that what you're telling me to do may work, some people said that they just splitted one partition and the new partition became bigger (letting them use all their disk space). Do you recommend me to do this on Recovery Mode?

Comment: Yeah, do it in recovery mode, backup before you start!

Comment: After losing almost all my space on my main disk, I entered on my Mavericks partition and resized my disks. The one with Mavericks finally could be resized to half my SSD, and the one with El Capitan couldn't be resized to half my SSD, BUT it could be to almost (I left 0.5 GB). I can't say that it's solved, but almost. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The .5 is because of corestorage